# If i close my terminal would a rake task started on Heroku continue to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake-task

I have a script which in need to run on my data. I have made a rake task for that. If i start the rake task by using `heroku run rake my_task:my_action` and after a while my internet disconnects. What would happen. Will the task continue to run as it has been initiated on a remote machine. I think it will continue to run. Any ideas.

Comment: why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Processes started in a [one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos) (the kind of dyno that is provisioned with `heroku run command`) run attached to your local terminal and will terminate if your internet disconnects or you cancel the command locally.

To execute a process in a one-off dyno that is *not* attached to your local terminal, [use `heroku run:detached`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#running-tasks-in-background):

```
$ heroku run:detached bundle exec rake my_task:my_action
Running `bundle exec rake my_task:my_action` detached... up, run.7562
Use `heroku logs -p run.7562` to view the output.
```

To introspect whether the one-off dyno is still running use `heroku ps`. One-off dynos are named `run.X` where `X` is some number.

Answer (score 1):

Guys so after trying and exploring i have found that in normal circumstances it doesnt continue. When the terminal closes pipes breaks and it stops to continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your rake in `screen` to prevent your script/rake from breaking if you get disconnected.

http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html